Some questions by new contributors don't go through the staging ground
The help center says:

When you ask your first questions on Stack Overflow, you will be guided through the Ask Wizard. When you submit your question, it will be posted into Staging Ground. Once the question is in Staging Ground, experienced users will be able to engage in back-and-forth discussion with you to help you improve your first posts.

Which leads me to the impression that all questions by new contributors should be going through the staging ground but it seems somehow questions can skip it.
For example
What effect does the placement of the reference symbol (ampersand) have in a simple loop? is by a new contributor as of today, with no other questions asked, yet there is no indication in the timeline that it ever went in or out of the staging ground.
Is this a bug? Or did I miss some condition that lets this question through to the main site immediately.
I've found nothing in the announcement post about it only applying to some questions either.

It's as intended. The SG is scaled with reviewer activity. In fact most questions don't go through SG. Not sure what the rate is but it's probably a lot closer to 10% than to 90%.

Interesting, that's not how the help center pages read and the announcement post doesn't seem to indicate that either.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/430407

This is behaviour as intended. The items entering Staging Ground is scaled with reviewer activity.
I asked for clarification in The return of Staging Ground to Stack Overflow related to the statement made there:

Finally, we will be closely monitoring the pace of new questions relative to active reviewers to ensure there is a healthy balance where asker's feel their questions are seen and reviewers aren't feeling overburdened.

The response from Slate was:

Only a certain volume of new users' posts will be directed to the Staging Ground. We are in control of that volume, and will try to make sure it doesn't get too far out of balance during the initial release stages. (Posts automatically graduate after some time without review as well, so there's a soft limit to the degree SG can be properly flooded.)


I would say the Help Center text is clearly wrong, then.
